# .Net core 6, not allowing login in iframe

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

our app works in https in prod, in appsettings file we got allowed CORS links like
"CorsPolicy": "https://app.xxx.co, ..."

in startup we got

```
      services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["CorsPolicy"].Split(' ').Select(x => x.Trim()).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray()).
                AllowAnyMethod().
                AllowAnyHeader().
                AllowCredentials();
            }
            );
        });
```

also

```
  `     if(Configuration["CorsPolicy"] != null && Configuration["CorsPolicy"].Length > 0)
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("content-security-policy",String.Format( "frame-ancestors 'self' {0}", Configuration["CorsPolicy"]));
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("x-frame-options", String.Format("allow-from {0}", Configuration["CorsPolicy"]));
                }`
```

Question is while app.xxx.co can open our app in iframe but while trying Login in iframe it returns

*Mixed Content: The page at 'https://app.xxx.co/accounting' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame 'http://panel.ourapp.com/?returnUrl=%2F'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

but our app works in https

I'm trying to understand what could happen and it becomes https to http

Comment: failed to reproduce,more details are required